# Google Analytics API and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, service, google-analytics-api

I'm using `google-api-client-0.8.2` and `Rails 4.2.3`. The service code I'm using is the one at http://www.slatestudio.com/blog/p/how-to-pull-google-analytics-data-from-rails-app. The env variables are all setted and I'm getting the environment variables from

```
# these from https://www.google.com/analytics/
GA_VIEW_ID: Admin > Select Site > View Tab > View Settings 
GA_APP_NAME: Home > name of folder with code in parenthesis

# these from https://console.developers.google.com/
GA_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL: Project > API > Credentials > 123@developer.gserviceaccount.com
GA_KEY_FILE_NAME: Same path above > P12 Key
```

I've also changed

```
service_account = Google::APIClient::JWTAsserter.new(
  ENV['GA_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL'], key)
```

to

```
service_account = Google::APIClient::JWTAsserter.new(
  ENV['GA_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL'],'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction', key)
```

Due `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 3..4) on jwt_asserter.rb:66:in 'initialize'`.

Every time I try to query using `#visitors` method I receive `Insuficient Permission`. What am I doing wrong?

### EDIT:

I've changed

```
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction' -> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly
```

And the message changed

`User does not have any Google Analytics account`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to give permission to the `123@developer.gservice...` on the

```
Manage > User Management tab
```